# Как правильно написать "орг()комитет"?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте! Сомневаюсь в правильности написания слова "орг()комитет". Есть вариант слитного написания: "оргкомитет" или раздельного: "орг. комитет". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: оргкомитет. Это сложносокращенное слово со значением "организационный комитет, создаваемый для подготовки и проведения каких-л. мероприятий".

Не имеет смысла использовать сокращение орг.комитет, если существует сложносокращенное слово.